# Force SVN to not check in portions of code

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

Is there any way to force TortoiseSVN to *ignore* or somehow skip over portions of code?

I have a situation where locally, I need to force some variables to behave a certain way by adding some dummy data.
Sometimes, the dummy data may lie there for days at a time while work continues - then they accidently get checked in.

Is there any way / method (Like maybe a special comment to wrap things around) that will tell TortoiseSVN to ignore the code within?

I understand I should just check every file before checking it in - but this process will make it a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any changes you DO need in those files, you can make use of TortoiseSVN's "ignore-on-commit" changelist.

In either the "check for modifications" or "commit" dialog, you can right-click on any file and add it to this special changelist. Once on the changelist, the files will by default be deselected in the commit dialog.

You CAN force SVN to commit them by manually selecting their checkbox, but mostly they will just stay locally modified.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell Subversion to conditionally commit portions of files. You can either commit the whole file, or not commit the whole file. There is no middle ground.